# UITextField text duplicate in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have this code

```
if (tableView.tag == RECO_TABLE) {
            CustomCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            NSString *roomName = [selectedRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.cellRoomName setText:roomName];
       return cell;
    }
```

And Inside my Custom Cell is

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellRoomName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cellRoomPrice;
```

**cellRoomName** is fine but **cellRoomPrice** keeps duplicating when my row reached >5 and I know the concept of reuse cell but I don't know how to start.

btw here's my sample scenario

Row 1 = 40

Row 2 = 2

Row 3 = null

Row 4 = null

Row 5 = null

Row 6 = 40

Row 7 = 2

So every 5th row my row gets duplicated.

Comment: I couldn't see any strange about this. Why you are said 5th row is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not setting the value of `cellRoomPrice` properly. If you already have this value for each row, you need to set it for each cell/row.

Since you are allowing user to edit room price, you need to store that value somewhere, preferably in an array indexed by row number. Assuming you have a `UITextFieldDelegate`, you also need to know the row number the user is editing(to store the value) on `-textFieldDidEndEditing:` which can be resolved by setting a tag on `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea... I've use NSDictionary as my data object and save it in NSUSerDefault so retrieve it back :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this because you are not checked cell is allocated or not.

```
if (tableView.tag == RECO_TABLE) {
    CustomCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    NSString *roomName = [selectedRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.cellRoomName setText:roomName];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few changes in code you need to do first of check for cell is nil or not

```
if (tableView.tag == RECO_TABLE) {
    CustomCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    NSString *roomName = [selectedRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.cellRoomName setText:roomName];
    return cell;
}
```

And then also the text you are typing in cell's text field need to store in some other array  say's "selectedRoomsPrices" and in "cellForRowAtIndexPath:" you need to check for counts and set that value as well in "cell.cellRoomPrice"  like this :

```
if (tableView.tag == RECO_TABLE) {
    CustomCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    NSString *roomName = [selectedRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.cellRoomName setText:roomName];
    NSString *roomPrice = @"";
    if(selectedPrices.count > indexPath.row) {
        roomPrice = [selectedRoomsPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [cell.cellRoomPrice setText:roomPrice];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your row reached > 5 is duplicated because i don't set value for it! TableView reuse before cell so if you don't set new value for it, tableview will use before cell!